# jquery dynamic id is not work. why?

Tags: jquery

**What is wrong?**

I am creating jQuery div dynamically but it is not working!

```
<body>

    <a id="main">Add DIV</a>

    <div id="parent"></div>

    <script>

    $(function(){

        var count = 0;

        $('#main').click(function(){
        $("<div />", {id: "new" + count})
            .append(count)
            .appendTo($('#parent'));
            count++;
        });
    });

    $("#new3").click(function(){
        alert("new3 clicked!");
    });

    </script>

</body>
```

is there any other method?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change .click with .on as the click event is attached to the elements created after the document is ready.

```
$(document).on('click','#new3',function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){


                                                
  var count = 0;                                // counter for elements
  var on_click_added=false;                     // boolan if click function exist
  $('#main').click(function(){
  $("<div />")
        .html('div id=>new'+count)               //add html code for clarity
        .attr('id', 'new' + count)               //add id attribute
        .appendTo($('#parent'));
    count++;

   if(($('#new3').length>0)&&(!on_click_added)){  //add on click function if element exist and not added early
         $('#new3').click(function(){
                  alert("new3 clicked!");
         });
         on_click_added=true;
   }

  });



});
```

```css
     div{
      margin: 10px;
      border-style:solid;
      border-width:1px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<a id="main">Add DIV</a>

<div id="parent"></div>
```